# How to make QNetworkReply read all received data EVEN IF http status is not 200 OK

Tags: qt, qnetworkreply

My problem is the following:

Response of `QNetworkReply::readAll` is empty when `QNetworkReply::error() != NoError`. Is this normal?

From the documentation of `QIODevice::readAll`:

> This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an empty
>   `QByteArray()` can mean either that no data was currently available
>   for reading, or that an error occurred.

That mean that every time http status is different from 200 OK `QNetworkReply` is unable to deliver other info that headers in response??

I've a Node+Express server that always send a detailed --json-- description in case of http status is different from 200; I cant get this description from my Qt client base on QNAM.

How can I change this behavior, I mean, make `QNetworkReply` read all received data EVEN IF http status is not 200 OK?

Qt version is 5.3, OS Win 7 64b.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal behavior. If you have an error, there is no response from server and no bytes from readAll() function.

Comment: I have an error code, but response is exist. You know, it's possible for server to return any code with any content.

Comment: If error code isn't 200 and the response isn't empty, then you can get your response using QNetworkReply::readAll() function. Just try it.